# Why does event handler wait until triggering code completes execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

The following snippet illustrates my question. I have some code that calls `jQuery.trigger` for a `customeventstart` event, followed by some intensive processing, and then it calls `jQuery.trigger` again for a `customeventstop` event.

I expected the event handler for `customeventstart` to execute immediately. However, there is a noticeable delay before the console displays the results of the `customeventstart` handler. It seems like the event handlers don't get called until after the triggering code finishes executing.

NOTE: You can adjust the number of iterations of the loop in the code snippet based on your machine's processing power to lengthen/shorten the delay.

```js
btn = $('#btn');

btn.on('click', function() {
  btn.trigger('customeventstart');
  
  // intensive/time-consuming processing
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    'string' + 'concatenation'; 
  }
  console.log('intensive processing done');
  
  btn.trigger('customeventstop');
});

btn.on('customeventstart', function() {
  console.log('starting');
});

btn.on('customeventstop', function() {
  console.log('stopping');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">This may take a while</button>
```

I plan to use an asynchronous [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage) solution, but I'd like to understand what is happening better.

**Why do handlers for `jQuery.trigger`ed events wait or seem to wait until the triggering code completes?**

Comment: All jQuery events, to my knowledge (there are probably exceptions as I'm not a god), execute synchronously. This may be what is giving you your noticeable "delay".

Comment: *"However, there is a noticeable delay before the console displays the results of the customeventstart handler."* On what browser? For me on Chrome, the delay is in the range of 0 to 8ms. Here's the Snippet I used to record those times: http://pastie.org/9975343 The times seem to match with what I see, as well, but humans are only accurate to about 50-100ms at best, and humans my age [48] probably toward the end of that scale. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the snippet. For me it's closer to 800 ms in Firefox. But this should be very system-dependent, right? I have other tabs/streaming video/software running right now. I'm working on a system that needs to scale up quite a bit (not really sure how much), thus my concern about keeping the UI responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this relates to the `console.log` implementation in Firefox (and Firebug) rather than the actual timing of the event.

I tried the following modification of your snippet, which basically just adds `Date.now` and a couple of more console log statements:

```js
btn = $('#btn');

btn.on('click', function() {
  console.log(Date.now() + ': triggering customeventstart');
  btn.trigger('customeventstart');
  
  // intensive/time-consuming processing
  console.log(Date.now() + ': starting intensive processing');
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    'string' + 'concatenation'; 
  }
  console.log(Date.now() + ': intensive processing done');
  
  console.log(Date.now() + ': triggering customeventstop');
  btn.trigger('customeventstop');
});

btn.on('customeventstart', function() {
  console.log(Date.now() + ': starting');
});

btn.on('customeventstop', function() {
  console.log(Date.now() + ': stopping');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">This may take a while</button>
```

For me:

- On Chrome and IE11, clicking the button results in near-instantaneous logging of the first three log statements (through "starting intensive processing"), followed by a delay, followed by the rest of the lines. And the sequence and timing are borne out by the timestamps on the lines.
- On Firefox, clicking the button results in a delay, then all the lines appear together — but if you look at the timestamps, it's clear that the delay actually happened between the "starting intensive processing" and "intensive processing done" log statements as with Chrome and IE11 (I had to add a 0 to the loop maximum to see this in Firefox — wow these things are fast these days):

```
"1424713006530: triggering customeventstart"
"1424713006530: starting"
"1424713006531: starting intensive processing"
"1424713007263: intensive processing done"
"1424713007263: triggering customeventstop"
"1424713007264: stopping"
```

So it's not that the event is being triggered after a delay, but that Firefox's `console.log` implementation appears to be held up if the main UI thread is busy.

This is very similar to the usual situation where the browser may not update the page's display while the main UI thread is busy. For instance, in the following snippet we turn the background of the button red while the intensive processing is going on (without using any custom events at all), then restore it when done; but on most browsers, you never see the button's background change at all even though there's plenty of time while the processing is happening:

```js
btn = $('#btn');

btn.on('click', function() {
  console.log(Date.now() + ': turning button background red');
  btn.css('background-color', 'red');
  
  // intensive/time-consuming processing
  console.log(Date.now() + ': starting intensive processing');
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    'string' + 'concatenation'; 
  }
  console.log(Date.now() + ': intensive processing done');
  
  console.log(Date.now() + ': restoring button background');
  btn.css('background-color', '');
});
```

```html
(Look in the console.)
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">This may take a while</button>
```

Comment: Interesting, but I think there's something else going on. I do get the results you are talking about in Chrome when the only thing I'm doing is logging. However, if I actually try to do things besides `console.log`s, I get the delay in both Chrome and FF. Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24ttk41c/2/.

Comment: @blcook223: That's a different thing entirely. It's not uncommon for browsers to *not* update the display while the main UI thread is intensively processing. You get the same effect without events: http://jsfiddle.net/24ttk41c/3/